# How do I copy all files in the source folder and in the subfolders in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, random, copy, subdirectory

I have a folder with many subfolders inside them, the subfolders have random numbers/characters as their name, and they all do have an important file in them. But how do i copy all the files in the source folder and in the subfolders to one folder without copy the folders, in a batchfile?

I use Windows7

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: XXcopy from http://www.xxcopy.com can `flatten` a folder tree when copying.

Comment: Will there be any filename collisions or will every filename be unique?

Comment: Every filename is unique...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be all you need.

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*) do copy "%%a" "c:\destination\folder"
```